# Error when using Chrome Debugger in VScode Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a program in javascript (see below) that I am trying to run using the Chrome Debugger extension in vscode. However, when I attempt to run the program I encounter an opened chrome window that gives the following error (see image).

```
 'use strict';
var msg = 'You entered:';
let promptInput = prompt("What would you like to enter");
console.log(msg);
console.log(promptInput);
```

I have done much searching about my problem, and have tried many different solutions with no success. Any specific information on how to solve this problem would be very helpful, thanks.

[Chrome Error Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/830I5.png)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a way to run the local file and not have to start a server. I am unsure of how to do this exactly though.

Comment: I have come across a solution, but not a complete fix to my problem. I learned that there is a way to run JS code in a the most common browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) using what is called 'Developer Tools'. You can find 'Developer Tools' in the Settings->More Tools->Developer Tools dropdown menu on Microsoft edge or by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I. Once you have the 'Developer Tools' sidebar open, navigate to the console tab and paste your JS code into the console. Then, press enter, and you will see your code manifest itself within your open browser window. I hope this helps, thanks.